# How to resolve this circular dependency?

Tags: c++

I have a interface for element that returns the mesh for the current element. I have mesh which is collection of element. The mesh also has reference to mesh because it want to manipulate mesh. When ever I try to compile I get error saying invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Mesh’.

AbsElem.h

```
class Mesh;

class AbsElem{
  virtual Mesh& GetMesh()const = 0;
};
```

Elem1.h

```
#include "AbsElem.h"
#include <vector>

class Elem1 : public AbsElem{

  Elem1(Mesh& m):my_mesh(m){}
  virtual Mesh& GetMesh() const{return my_mesh;}

  void DoStuff(){
   my_mesh.GetVal();
  }

  Mesh& my_mesh;
};
```

Mesh.h

```
#include "Elem1.h"

class Mesh{
  public: 
  int GetVal(){return 1;}
  private:
  std::vector<Elem1> collect_elem_;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Mesh.h"

int main(){
  Mesh m;
}
```

compile by : `g++ main.cpp`

compilation error :

> In file included from Mesh.h:1,
>                    from main.cpp:1: Elem1.h: In member function ‘void Elem1::DoStuff()’: Elem1.h:10:4: error: invalid use of incomplete type
>   ‘class Mesh’
>       my_mesh.GetVal();
>       ^~~~~~~ In file included from Elem1.h:1,
>                    from Mesh.h:1,
>                    from main.cpp:1: AbsElem.h:2:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class Mesh’  class Mesh;
>          ^~~~

Comment: Please post the exact full error message from your compiler including filenames and line numbers.

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Elem1>> collect_elem_;`

Comment: You should just create `Elem1.c` with `Elem1::DoStuff()` definition and remove the definition from `Elem1.h` file. You can't use incomplete type.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Elem1>> collect_elem_;` give even more error.

Comment: @mato Include the [correct headers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) as necessary of course.

Comment: @mato Also move `virtual Mesh& GetMesh() const{return my_mesh;}` out into a separate compilation unit.